# Disable Shift+Delete Cutting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I type fast. Often times when programming I will select a line with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> and then press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key, but I do this so quickly that my finger hasn't come off of the <kbd>shift</kbd> key. This results in replacing clipboard item with what was selected.

This is bad because many times I am deleting code before pasting some other code.

Apparently <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> is an old school way of cutting.

I am aware of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> for cycling through clipboard history in visual studio, but this is still terribly annoying.

Is there a way to disable this shortcut in visual studio or windows in general?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts are pretty thoroughly customizable in Visual Studio.

Go to `Tools > Options` then in the left select `Environment > Keyboard`

Select the command, select the shortcut you want to remove, click "Remove" and click "OK"

[image]

If you wanted to circumvent this across Windows, you can use a one-line [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to convert <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to just plain <kbd>Delete</kbd>:

```
+DELETE::SendInput,{DELETE}
```

Comment: how do I find my hotkey inbetween those 10000000 entries?

Comment: @user2212907 You can search in the box that says "Show commands containing." If you are trying to find out which command is using a particular hotkey, you can enter that hotkey in the box that says "Press shortcut keys" as though you are going to assign it. At the bottom of a dialog is a dropdown that will show the command(s) to which the hotkey is already assigned.

Comment: Edit.Cut has two shortucts: Ctr+X and Shift+Del. I removed Shift+Dl from cut and assigned it to Edit.LineDelete.

Comment: +1 This answer also works in Programmer's Notepad: Go to `Tools->Options`, select `Keyboard` and scroll down until you find `Edit -> Cut`, then just delete the `Shift+Del` shortcut.

Comment: Not exactly related to question, but I find myself updating clipboard with some random content pretty often. That's why I started to use Ditto (but there are more clipboard managers available), it literally saves lives!

Answer (score 50):

Good answer. Although I assume some people will still like to perform the delete operation.

To still perform the wipe of the entire line with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> but don't add it to the clipboard:

remove (as explained above) the binding of SHIFT+DEL to the Edit.Cut command

AND

bind the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> combination to the `Edit.LineDelete` command.

Comment: That looks tedious. Why not simply press DEL to delete without adding to clipboard?

Comment: Because pressing DEL only deletes 'character by character', SHIFT+DEL deletes the entire line at once, which saved a lot of time and frustration, you should give it a try (:

Comment: I love you :D just the thing I was looking for

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks from the future!

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way.
The shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> simply deletes the line you're on. Without having to select it first and without copying it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

This autohotkey script solve this globally:

```
+Delete::
KeyWait Shift
Send {Delete}
```

shift+insert is okay, but shift+delete is just plain EVIL

I actually often lost code entirely, while being utterly confused where'd it go! :-)